# ASP.NET Entity Framework DataContext use issue

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, datacontext

I 've built an ASP.NET website using EF. I created a DataContext class which implements the singleton pattern. My DAO classes (singletons too) instanciate this datacontext and store it in a property. They use it in order to query the SQLServer DataBase. This worked ok for 3 months but I suddenly got exception messages like :"Connection must be valid and open / connection already open". It seemed that datacontext was not disposed. The only change, according to me, was the data size and number of users increasing.

I then found multiple posts saying that singleton was a bad idea foe datacontext, so I tried to instanciate datacontext in a using statement in every request and that resolved the problem, except for update queries which had no effects in database. I had to attach the db object to the context and then set its EntityState to "modified" to have my SaveChanges work.

Like this :

```
public bool DoucheXpsu(as_headers session) {
    using (MyDBEntities MyContext = new MyDBEntities()) {

        try {
            as_status status = GetStatus(session);
            if (status != null) {
                if (status.mainstatusvalue == 300) {
                    status.DateDoucheXpsu = DateTime.Now;
                    status.DoucheXpsu = 1;

                    MyContext.as_status.Attach(status);
                    MyContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(status, EntityState.Modified);

                    MyContext.SaveChanges();

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException) {
            return false;
        } catch (Exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it actually didn't work for ONE method (which has nothing different from the other update method) !
        The exception occured as I tried to attach the object : "The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state. " So I had to comment the attach and ChangeObjectState methods to have it work as expected :

```
public bool SetSessionToDelete(string numSession) {
    using (MyDBEntities MyContext = new MyDBEntities()) {
        try {
            view_headerStatus view = (from v in MyContext.view_headerStatus
                                      where v.CodeSession == numSession
                                      where v.lastinserted == 1
                                      select v).First();

            if (view != null) {
                as_status status = (from s in MyContext.as_status
                                    where s.jobclsid == view.jobclsid
                                    where s.lastinserted == 1
                                    select s).First();
                if (status != null) {
                    status.DeleteSession = 1;
                    //MyContext.as_status.Attach(status);
                    //MyContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(status, EntityState.Modified);
                   MyContext.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        } catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException) {
            return false;
        } catch (Exception) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The question is WHY should this one behave differently ???
        I've read many posts about EF and dataContext but I feel I'm missing something. I would be glad if anyone can help.
        Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, this line here:

```
as_status status = GetStatus(session);
```

I would assume this populates using a DIFFERENT context, and when it leaves the GetStatus() method the context it used to load is disposed.  That is why your subsequent Attach() works.  However in your second example you do not need to attach because it was loaded using the current (connected) context.

To solve you may want to either pass the context to your methods like GetStatus() resulting in no need to reattach.  I don't typically reattach unless I am resurrecting an object over the wire or from a file.

Comment: Gee! you are right, of course ! It sounds obvious now you say it. Thanks, it is really helpful.